# Where is the relative gap from cplexbilp?

Tags: cplex, matlab

I am invoking `cplexbilp` (CPLEX 12.9) from Matlab R2022a.  I request all 4 return arguments:

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = cplexbilp(...)
```

I use the variable browser to browse the 4 outputs.  Nowhere is there a relative gap.  I set the options to terminate at a relative gap of 1e-4 (0.01%), but I'd like to know what the actual relative gap is.  I know that for lengthy enough searches, the display console will show periodic updates, but my problem is solved immediately (albeit with "numerical issues").  Will "numerical issues" prevent the appearance of a relative gap in (say) the "output" argument above, or is the relative gap simply not returned?

P.S. If instead I can just get the best-bound, it would be simple to calculate the relative gap.